# Synchronous timestamp with milliseconds precision across device and platforms

Tags: android, ios, file, audio, timestamp

I am creating an audio-recording APP.

I will be merging recordings from multiple devices (both Android and IOS).
In order to make the files synchronous I need to know when each user initiated their recordings.
So after the recording is initiated, for Android it is after startRecording() has been called, I need to create a timestamp.
I will then compare the timestamp from each device to know the delay to add to each recording.

Is there a timestamp that regardless of device, timezone, API etc. etc. is synchronous?

Instead of creating the timestamp after the recording has been initiated I have also tried using lastModified() to get the file creation date and time. The problem with this approach is that the time does not include milliseconds.

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis()? It's based on the Unix timestamp * 1000.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exist.  There is no time system synchronized across all devices like that.  Definitely not down to the millisecond-  you'd get clock skew just from the network delay trying to synchronize.  If your app depends on this it just isn't feasible.  I highly suggest you read https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time.